# smoothScrollToPosition on Backpressed

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(ll_details_container.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
        ll_details_container.setAlpha(1.0f);
        ll_details_container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lv_reviews.smoothScrollToPosition(1);

    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

I was expecting with a single back press click will execute all the code inside if(true) clause, but with the first click only execute smoothScrollToPosition and then i have to click again for execute VISIBILITY line. I could not understand.

Comment: try to run your code with comment the smoothScrollToPosition line. will it behave same?

Comment: How is that possible? What is `ll_details_container` anyway? I'm sure those lines get executed, but it may just not be in the view at that moment or something.

Comment: when you set the ll_details_container gone? can you supply some detail code?

Comment: i have resolved this problem.